# 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command - Visual Studio output

Tags: svn, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I am running:
Windows 8 x64
Visual Studio 2013
Slik Subversion

In my csproj file I have the following to pull from SVN repository before build

`<Target Name="BeforeBuild">

    <Exec ContinueOnError="true" Command="svn co --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username MY_USERNAME --password MY_PASSWORD https://MY_SVN_REPOSITORY $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\SUB_DIRECTORY" />

</Target>`

In the output window I get:

`'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Why can I run this command successfully from command prompt but not visual studio?

`svn co --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username MY_USERNAME --password MY_PASSWORD https://MY_SVN_REPOSITORY $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\SUB_DIRECTORY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try prefixing your command with "cmd /c", include the full path to svn, or make sure the location of svn appears somewhere in your %path% environment variable.

If this is a common location, hard code it into a property referenced in the exec task:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
    <SvnDir>c:\programfiles\svn\</SvnDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<Exec ContinueOnError="true" Command="$(SvnDir)svn co --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username MY_USERNAME --password MY_PASSWORD https://MY_SVN_REPOSITORY $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\SUB_DIRECTORY" />
</Target>
```

EDIT: Edited to show you can configure that folder, however granadacoder has a nice solution that can be easily integrated into a build solution.

Comment: Full path to svn works for me but it is a group project so it won't always work. %path% environment variable is set, that is why it works in cmd. It seems like Visual Studio cannot access it. If possible I just want it to access %path%

Comment: Is the path set as a system environment variable?  You could also prefix the command with "set path=%path%;&lt;path&gt;&amp;&amp;&lt;svn_command&gt;"... one sec, going to update my post.

Comment: It must have been a user environment variable. I added to as a system environment variable and it works now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Type "set" in the dos command window.

and look at the "path".

You'll probably see the folder where "svn.exe" is located.

Your msbuild probably can't see it.

But there is a better way.

Get and install the MSBuild Community Tasks.........and they have a svn Task.
It makes it easier than coding up the EXEC command.

Alot of custom Msbuild Tasks are exactly that.  They simply wrap the command-line call, but give you settable properties instead of wiring up the exec command.

https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/tree/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/Subversion

One example

```
 <SvnExport RepositoryPath="file:///d:/svn/repo/Test/trunk"
 LocalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Test\Export">
 <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
 </SvnExport>
```

Or, if the msbuild extension pack is more you're cup of tea.

http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/bccddf04-f5ee-21d4-0f64-bb1b42b08257.htm

```
    <!-- Export -->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Subversion.Svn TaskAction="Export" Item="c:\path\workingcopy" Destination="c:\path\exported"/>
```

I use both.  And you'll "get your money's worth" many times over using these very helpful add-on tasks.  Aka, its worth the small install effort to get them up and running.

Comment: This option looks interesting but I prefer not to add any extensions since it would then require all developers to install as well. On my next individual project I might give this a try.